# Where does nikto tool store its default reports?

Tags: vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners

I ran the [nikto](https://cirt.net/Nikto2) security scan tool against one of our dev sites.

```
perl nikto.pl -h mydevsitename
```

The output mentioned

```
7646 requests: 14 error(s) and 3 item(s) reported on remote host
```

None of the errors were printed on the screen, where can I find more info about these errors that it indicated? or where does it stores its reports by default?

Comment: Check your `nikto.conf` file for the location. The manual explains: https://cirt.net/nikto2-docs/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
perl nikto.pl -verbose -h example.com
```

Also look up `-output` parameter in nikto manual.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the verbosity while launching the command.

`nikto -Display -verbose -host example.com`

Also if you are using a nix system you can navigate to

`/etc/nikto.conf`

Here you can find all the nikto related files. You can find something like this:

```
*Location of Nikto*  
EXECDIR=/var/lib/nikto   
*Location of plugin dir*  
PLUGINDIR=/var/lib/nikto/plugins  
*Location of database dir*    
DBDIR=/var/lib//nikto/databases  
*Location of template dir*  
TEMPLATEDIR=/var/lib/nikto/templates  
*Location of docs dir*  
DOCDIR=/var/lib/nikto/docs
```

Answer (score -1):

You should run:

```
perl nikto.pl -h example.com > outputfile.txt
```

Then it will be written in outputfile.txt.

Comment: That wont work since it will just add to output file what it prints on screen which is "7646 requests: 14 error(s) and 3 item(s) reported on remote host" . I need to see actual detail information on those errors.